# Is there any way to run PHP on Android

Tags: php, android, webserver

I've tried to open my PHP script in the built in Android browser, but I only see my code, as text, and the PHP doesn't run. Why is that ?

How can I run PHP on my Android device ? Is there a way to set up PHP and a web server on an Android device ?

Comment: Are you asking if you can edit and run a php file on an android file or simply load a php page in your web browser. Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: PHP is a language that is used on a web _server_ (http server), not on a web _client_ (browser). So the fact that you have a browser on android has _nothing_ to do with the ability to interpret php scripts. For that you'd have to install php on Android. That certainly should be possible, but it sounds very "wrong". An android device is not typically used as a server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHP is a language that is used on a web *server* (http server), not on a *web client* (browser). This means that in order to run PHP *on* your android device (and not just display a web page served from a web server hosted elsewhere, online), you need to install a web server on your device. Luckily there's a few apps which provide this functionality.

- [Web Server PHP/MyAdmin/MySQL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nokshaserv)
- [AWebServer ( Http Web Server A](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sylkat.apache)
- In the past, I've had success with the free [Palapa Web Server](http://alfanla.com/palapa-web-server/) which is essentially a web / mysql server which runs on Android, which will run your PHP scripts, and it will also work offline. But this one no longer exists.

  To use Palapa web server, install the app, and copy your PHP / HTML files onto your phone. By default, the Palapa Web server uses `/sdcard/pws/www/`, so if you put your files there, it should pick them up. Then, launch the app, click "Start server", and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` with your web browser on your android device, and it should work. Other web server apps will work similarly.

Note that setting up PHPMyAdmin, (if you need that for managing databases) can be a bit tricky, as you will need to download the extra packages for it, if the app you're using does not bundle it.