# Can I run untrusted code such as PHP language?

Tags: android

Is there a way that I can complie/debug/run php codes on Android and can also present types of errors?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can install a server on your device and use it - although I'm not sure what it will give you.

One example is this :[Server for PhP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.php&hl=en). There are others, you can also look at this SO answer: [Is there any way to run PHP on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245837/is-there-any-way-to-run-php-on-android)