# Android development : performing particular task to retrieve data

Tags: android, xml, database

I consider to begin creation of an Android app, about a famous card game, named "Magic the Gathering". 
My main question is how can I achieve a very important task.

Let's take an example. In this game, there's over 15k different cards. One of my goals is to make an Activity (with a search field for example), where cards are displayed.
I suppose I can do that with an xml file, or a database, but I don't really know how I can populate this one (not manually I hope), nor create it (I don't know database creation very well).

If you want a concrete example, get the app "TopDecked", and look the "cards and price" menu. I want to do something like that. Not really the same (I don't want to copy their code of course), but I need some idea to perform that task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a DB in a offline server (ex: Xampp, Wampp, etc) and connect the DB to it using PHP. Here is a link in the right direction: [Is there any way to run PHP on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245837/is-there-any-way-to-run-php-on-android)

Comment: Oh yes, Xampp is a good idea. Btw, i found a json file who contains all data i need (almost 900k lines)... I think it will be more easily to interpret this json file inside android. Thank's for your answer anyway.