# I want my Android App to sync data to MYSQL for my Online ERP

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I'm creating an online erp system, my erp stores data in a MySQL database on-line. It also retrieves data using PHP code, performs calculations on the server and sends the result back to the user.

Data it's quite simple: purchase record, sales record, expense record, to do list etc that are read from the database and manipulated on the server side.

Often client work in environments where the internet connection is poor or not available. In this case I would like the client to be able to work offline: i.e, enter purchase record, sales record, expense record, to do list etc to perform calculations. Then synchronise all data as soon as a connection is available.

All offline activities will be performed on an android application and I want to sync all data like purchase record, sales record, expense record, to do list etc to its database so that it will be available for its web version i.e, online erp.

I dont want to use firebase because mySQL is economical for me and also i want to fetch same syncd data to its web version.

Now the problem is that I do not know what is the best way or technologies for achieving this. Don't worry, I am not asking to write code for me. Can you just explain to me what is the correct way to build such a system?

Is there a simple way to use my online MySQL and PHP code locally?

Should I use two MySQL database, one local and one online and do a synchronisation between the two when data is available? If yes which technology (language) shall I use to perform this operation?

If possible, I would like an answer from PHP coders that worked on a similar project in the past and can give me detailed information on framework structure and technology to use. please remember that I am new to this way of writing application and I would appreciate if you can spare few minutes and explain everything to me like if I am six year old or stupid (which I am!)

I really appreciate any help and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install xampp for the server here you can host "localhost" for your client. this is what we call intranet. ounce installed you can just put your project in "htdocs" folder, with this done. you can test your project using "http://localhost/myproject" or you can test this inside your network using server's IP like "http://192.168.1.2/myproject" or your server name like "http://myserver/myproject"

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to add all operations in your android app to a queue, and when there is a sufficient network connection, remove items from the queue and send them for processing to your backend (ie your php and mysql erp service).

After researching this, it seems like your php backend code will not be reusable in your android app (unless you want, in my opinion, hacky or dependency hell solutions ([See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245837/is-there-any-way-to-run-php-on-android))).

In order to get your android app (and therein the queue talked about above) working smoothly, you should build an api endpoint in your php code and then implement the api in your android app in order to send the update/upload requests easily.

In summery,

queue inside android app which can use [this android queue implementation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue) ->

queue stacks requests until the connection is sufficient for processing->

using api, send requests to php backend->

have api endpoint handle requests from android app;

This seems like a pretty hard project all in all, so good luck!